# How to write this for iteration in scala without using the For( loop; if condition) and still use yield properlly

Tags: scala

Hi I am a Scala student not really a lot of experience in it.

I been trying to make something like this

```
object FileMatcher {
    private def filesHere = (new java.io.File(".")).listFiles

    private def filesMatching(matcher: String => Boolean) =
        for (file <- filesHere; if matcher(file.getName))
            yield file.getName

    def filesEnding(query: String) = filesMatching(_.endsWith(query))
    def filesContaining(query: String) = filesMatching(_.contains(query))
    def filesRegex(query: String) = filesMatching(_.matches(query))
}
```

work with this syntax 
( I honestly don't like or have reached the ilumination to undestand why shoud I use FORs like that yet. maybe it will come... )

```
object FileMatcher {
    private def filesHere = (new java.io.File(".")).listFiles

    private def filesMatching(matcher: String => Boolean) =
        for (file <- filesHere)
                 yield
            if (matcher(file.getName))
                file.getName

    def filesEnding(query: String) = filesMatching(_.endsWith(query))
    def filesContaining(query: String) = filesMatching(_.contains(query))
    def filesRegex(query: String) = filesMatching(_.matches(query))
}
```

So what I would like to know is

How can I yield a value without getting the return of the If in this last form ?

Right now my outputs with this running  this :

```
FileMatcher.filesEnding("scala")
```

in the order of code show are

```
***.scala
```

and the next goes

```
(),(),(),(),***.scala,(),(),()
```

Because the if is returning it's values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first expression

```
for (file <- filesHere; if matcher(file.getName))
        yield file.getName
```

due to for comprehension is translated to

```
filesHere.filter(file => matcher(file.getName)).map(file => file.getName)
```

where `file => file.getName` returns `String` on filtered collection.
and the second one

```
for (file <- filesHere)
             yield
        if (matcher(file.getName))
            file.getName
```

translated to

```
filesHere.map(file => if (matcher(file.getName)) file.getName)
```

where `file => if (matcher(file.getName)) file.getName` rerurns `Any` which you can see in output as `()`

Comment: Hum... ok, nice. But how to use the For with a nested If to yield only the if passed values ? it it possible at all? Is it possible to do that without using this kind of For(loop; if) syntax

Comment: Not really. There are two forms of the for loop: "for (enumeration) exp" and "for (enumeration) yield exp". yield cannot appear anywhere except in that second form. It is not a statement of its own, it's a "fixed" part of the for loop construct. It is syntactical sugar for "enumeration.map(exp)".

Comment: No. It can be achieved only with `for(expr1;if expr2) yeild expr2` syntax, which is translated to `expr1.filter(expr2).map(expr3)`. Read [Translation of for expressions](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/for-expressions-revisited.html#23.4) for detailed explanation of `for comprehension`.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
private def filesMatching(matcher: String => Boolean) =
  filesHere.filter(file => matcher(file.getName)).map(file => file.getName)
```

Comment: Thanks ! but my question still lasts. Is this the only way ? can't I use For and Ifs ? with yield in the middle ?